# Do I unit test the correct thing

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Thats my method to test:

```
   public LessonplannerRequest GetWeeklyLessonplanner(int schoolyearId)  
        {            
            Schoolyear schoolyear = _unitOfWork.SchoolyearRepository.GetById(schoolyearId);
            DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek = schoolyear.FirstDayOfWeek;

            DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
            DateTime startDateOfWeek = _dateService.GetFirstDateOfWeek(currentDate, firstDayOfWeek);
            DateTime endDateOfWeek = _dateService.GetLastDateOfWeek(currentDate, firstDayOfWeek);

            var periods = _unitOfWork.PeriodRepository.GetWeeklyPeriods(schoolyearId, startDateOfWeek, endDateOfWeek );
            var weeks = _dateService.GetAllWeekStartingDays(startDateOfWeek, endDateOfWeek, firstDayOfWeek);
            var request = new LessonplannerRequest
            {
                 Periods = periods,
                 Weeks = weeks,
            };

            return request;
        }
```

Thats my unit test:

```
 // Arrange
            Mock<IUnitOfWork> unitOfWorkMock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
            Mock<IDateService> dateServiceMock = new Mock<IDateService>();
            Mock<TLPContext> contextMock = new Mock<TLPContext>();
            Mock<IGenericRepository<Schoolyear>> schoolyearRepositoryMock = new Mock<IGenericRepository<Schoolyear>>();
            Mock<ILessonplannerRepository> lessonplannerRepoMock = new Mock<ILessonplannerRepository>();

            int schoolyearId = 1;
            DateTime start = new DateTime(2010, 1, 1);
            DateTime end = new DateTime(2010, 1, 2);

            unitOfWorkMock.Setup(s => s.SchoolyearRepository).Returns(schoolyearRepositoryMock.Object);
            unitOfWorkMock.Setup(s => s.PeriodRepository).Returns(lessonplannerRepoMock.Object);
            dateServiceMock.Setup(s => s.GetFirstDateOfWeek(DateTime.Now.Date, DayOfWeek.Sunday)).Returns(start);
            dateServiceMock.Setup(s => s.GetLastDateOfWeek(DateTime.Now.Date, DayOfWeek.Sunday)).Returns(end);
            schoolyearRepositoryMock.Setup(s => s.GetById(schoolyearId)).Returns(new Schoolyear() { FirstDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday });

            ILessonplannerService service = new LessonplannerService(unitOfWorkMock.Object, dateServiceMock.Object);            

            // Act
            LessonplannerRequest request = service.GetWeeklyLessonplanner(schoolyearId);

            // Assert         
            dateServiceMock.Verify(d => d.GetFirstDateOfWeek(DateTime.Now.Date, DayOfWeek.Sunday));
            dateServiceMock.Verify(d => d.GetLastDateOfWeek(DateTime.Now.Date, DayOfWeek.Sunday));
            lessonplannerRepoMock.Verify(d => d.GetWeeklyPeriods(schoolyearId, start, end));

            Assert.That(request.Periods, Is.Empty);
            Assert.That(request.Weeks, Is.Empty);
```

In my method to test all calls to a repository or dateService are already unit tested itself thus I am mocking them not to have an integration test...

I ask myself wether my assertion for empty lists make sense. And If not what would you test. Actually in this method everything is already tested just the creation of the LessonplannerRequest is not tested...

Comment: My very first impression is that your `GetWeeklyLessonPlanner()` method and its class might be doing too much. How much more than the method to test is there in the class? Is it just that method, the constructor and dependency fields? Generally try and post complete classes; that will make it easier for others to get the code working and provide assistance.

Comment: There is still a SaveLessonplanner() method with 5 lines of code. Why do you have the impression, that my class is doing too much?

Comment: Just a first thought when I saw that `IUnitOfWork` is actually hiding an additional dependency of your method. I'm still figuring out what's actually happening.

Comment: "I'm still figuring out what's actually happening" Then when  did you your last mocking parade? ;P

Comment: A few weeks back probably. My confusion wasn't so much about the test/mocks, but more about what the code under test actually does (and I still don't understand the greater purpose).

Comment: "and I still don't understand the greater purpose" maybe therefore I did this question ;-)

Comment: @Elisa can you provide the code for `IDateService` implementation (`GetFirstDateOfWeek`, `GetLastDateOfWeek`, `GetAllWeekStartingDays` methods)? Obviously it's not under test, but in my answer I suggested to refactor it based on assumptions that may not be correct...

Comment: all these 3 methods could also be written as extension methods almaz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to almaz' correct answer (except for using `SetUp` in NUnit, which is risky and can have dangerous side effects), I wouldn't test for empty collections, because those can come from anywhere and could well be the default for the properties of `LessonplannerRequest`.

Instead, set up your mocks (which are now actually stubs because we're not verifying the calls to their methods) to return specific objects for the correct method invocations, and then assert that those objects are returned in your request object:

```
[Test]
public void GetWeeklyLessonPlanner_ReturnsCorrectRequest()
{
    // Arrange
    Mock<IUnitOfWork> unitOfWorkMock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
    Mock<IDateService> dateServiceMock = new Mock<IDateService>();
    Mock<IGenericRepository<Schoolyear>> schoolyearRepositoryMock = new Mock<IGenericRepository<Schoolyear>>();
    Mock<ILessonplannerRepository> lessonplannerRepoMock = new Mock<ILessonplannerRepository>();

    int schoolyearId = 1;
    DateTime start = new DateTime(2010, 1, 1);
    DateTime end = new DateTime(2010, 1, 2);

    unitOfWorkMock.Setup(s => s.SchoolyearRepository).Returns(schoolyearRepositoryMock.Object);
    unitOfWorkMock.Setup(s => s.PeriodRepository).Returns(lessonplannerRepoMock.Object);
    dateServiceMock.Setup(s => s.GetFirstDateOfWeek(DateTime.Now.Date, DayOfWeek.Sunday)).Returns(start);
    dateServiceMock.Setup(s => s.GetLastDateOfWeek(DateTime.Now.Date, DayOfWeek.Sunday)).Returns(end);

    var dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday;
    schoolyearRepositoryMock.Setup(s => s.GetById(schoolyearId)).Returns(new Schoolyear() { FirstDayOfWeek = dayOfWeek });

    var expectedPeriods = new List<object>() { new object() };
    lessonplannerRepoMock.Setup(r => r.GetWeeklyPeriods(schoolyearId, start, end)).Returns(expectedPeriods);

    var expectedWeeks = new List<object>() { new object() };
    dateServiceMock.Setup(d => d.GetAllWeekStartingDays(start, end, dayOfWeek)).Returns(expectedWeeks);

    LessonplannerService service = new LessonplannerService(unitOfWorkMock.Object, dateServiceMock.Object);

    // Act
    LessonplannerRequest request = service.GetWeeklyLessonplanner(schoolyearId);

    // Assert
    Assert.That(request.Periods, Is.SameAs(expectedPeriods));
    Assert.That(request.Weeks, Is.SameAs(expectedWeeks));
}
```

This will make sure that your stub objects' methods are called with the correct parameters, because the expected objects are only returned for those specific parameter combinations, and at the same time guarantee that those values are correctly used further on, because they are particular object references that the test can explicitly recognize.

Note that the `List<object>` will probably have to be something else in your actual code. Your code fragments didn't contain types for `Periods` and `Weeks`, so I used `IEnumerable<object>` to work with.

Comment: Can you shed a light on side effects of using `SetUp`? I'm using it for about 8 years now and haven't noticed anything dangerous...

Comment: Then you probably have a very tidy approach that doesn't let those issues come to bear. Many people will not have that. This is from James Newkirk, who led NUnit development for years before starting xUnit.net because he became dissatisfied with NUnit: http://jamesnewkirk.typepad.com/posts/2007/09/why-you-should-.html

Comment: @GCATNM Its an IEnumerable<Period> periods... :)

Answer (score 3):

Almost everything is perfect. Some notes:

- Do use `var` to avoid repeating in cases like `Mock<IUnitOfWork> unitOfWorkMock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>()`
- Move mocks initialisation and wiring up to `SetUp` method to avoid copy-pasting in different test methods, and leave only actual setups that provide test data in test method
- It's hard to unit test the code that uses `DateTime.Now`. For example your test may fail when running near midnight (since you call `DateTime.Now` several times, and subsequent calls may return the next day). I would suggest to add the `UtcNow` property to your `IDateService` and always use it instead of `DateTime.Now` (I prefer to force using UTC time since it forces you to think about time zones). Then, most likely you won't need methods like `GetFirstDateOfWeek` in `IDateService` (if they depend on inputs only), they could be just extension methods to `DateTime`.
- You don't need to verify that `GetFirstDateOfWeek` and `GetLastDateOfWeek` were called, just make sure that result matches expected value. The reason is because the call to those methods does not guarantee that returned values were used correctly. And when all tests pass without those calls - it only shows that you should add more tests to verify that returned values were used properly

As a result you'll have something like this:

```
[Test]
public void WhenWeekStartOnSunday...ShouldReturnSomething
{
    const int schoolyearId = 1;
    var currentDate = new DateTime(2010, 1, 1).ToUniversalTime();
    var periods = new [] {...}; //specify test periods here

    //Arrange
    _schoolyearRepositoryMock.Setup(s => s.GetById(schoolyearId)).Returns(new Schoolyear() { FirstDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday });       
    _dateServiceMock.Setup(s => s.UtcNow).Returns(currentDate);
    _lessonplannerRepoMock.Setup(lp => lp.GetWeeklyPeriods(schoolyearId, new DateTime(2010, 1, 1), 
            new DateTime(2010, 1, 5))) //specify the dates expected according to "currentDate" value.
        .Returns(periods);

    var service = new LessonplannerService(_unitOfWorkMock.Object, _dateServiceMock.Object);            

    // Act
    LessonplannerRequest request = service.GetWeeklyLessonplanner(schoolyearId);

    // Assert         
    Assert.That(request.Periods, Is.SameAs(periods));
    Assert.That(request.Weeks, Is.Empty); //verify here expected list of weeks according to logic of the method
}
```

Comment: I'd go one further and say that schoolyearId should be const.

Comment: @almaz "The reason is because the call to those methods does not guarantee that returned values were used correctly" But the call to those methods guarantee that the methods are called at all. What do you think?

Comment: @Elisa what if you find the way to avoid calling those methods and yet produce proper results? Then you would have to change unit tests because they started to fail. If values returned by e.g. `GetFirstDateOfWeek` are actually valuable, then in certain use cases output  will depend on them, and there should be a test that checks it. If there is no way to verify the proper usage of `GetFirstDateOfWeek`... then it does not influence results, and it means that you don't need to call it :).

Comment: You need to verify mock method calls when it is the function being tested, e.g. when functionality under test should send an email you would write assertion as `_emailSenderMock.Verify(e = > e.SendEmail(expected_parameters));`

Comment: Updated the answer to verify that periods are passed through

Comment: I don't agree with the reasoning for testing `Weeks` for emptiness instead of a specific instance. You're making an assumption about implementation details of the `IDateService` instance, while actually for what is to be tested the exact dates are completely irrelevant. The start date could even be after the end date, and the `LessonplannerService` class - and its tests - should still work correctly, because it just ties those other services together. (I wouldn't even have chosen the dates myself but created them with AutoFixture for that very reason.)

Comment: @GCATNM I don't know the implementation of `IDateService`. I assumed that most of the methods (like `GetFirstDateOfWeek`) are pure methods, that is depend on input values only. In this case I suggested to move those methods to `DateTime`'s extension methods. In case if it depends on `IDateService` state then yes, you would need to do a setup and check for the same value in result as in your answer

Comment: @almaz I think I misunderstood the comment after that last line; I didn't get that this was more of a "to be done" for the asker than a justification for testing on emptiness. At any rate, I don't understand what the difference would be between testing for a specific instance in `Periods`, which you did, and setting up the `IDateService` stub with an instance for `Weeks`, which you didn't. That value does not depend on any decision in `LessonplannerService`, but solely on the return value of `IDateService.GetAllWeekStartingDays()`.

Comment: @Guys maybe that was a bad example from me. I asserted an empty because I expect nothing to come as a result because my mocks do not setup data and return it. But in almaz solution he provides mock data.

Comment: @GCATNM yes the dates are completely irrelevant as I do not return anything from the mock data(hope I understood you right...) Thats also what my initial question is about : "Do I test the right thing..." Yes my startdate could be after the end date in the UNIT TEST but not in real as the date is validated on the web server.

Comment: @Elisa The dates are irrelevant because the class under test does never look at them at all but just passes them around. The other classes involved may care about them, but they are stubbed out in this test, so the values never matter. The only thing this class does is tie a few services together; it doesn't even make any decisions, so the only thing there is to test is if it puts all the parameters in the right places and returns the correct values from those other services.

Comment: @GCATNM Yes true the only this class is doing is just tie a few services together there is no class extra logic.

Comment: @almaz I upvoted your answer but gave the solution to GCATNM :) it was hard to choose between 2 good answers...